# MSIL: Why does Array initializer use dup

Tags: c#, cil

I'm learning MSIL recently, and got some confusing about array:
Below 2 method:

```
private static void FormatTest3()
{
    string s = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", 1, 2,3);
}

private static void FormatTest4()
{
    string s = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", 1, 2,3,4);
    /*
    equal to
    object[] obj = new object[4];
    obj[0] = 1;
    obj[1] = 2;
    obj[2] = 3;
    obj[3] = 4;
    string text = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", obj);
    */
}
```

And here is the IL:

```
.class private auto ansi '<Module>'
{
} // end of class <Module>

.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit Program
    extends [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Object
{
    // Methods
    .method private hidebysig static 
        void FormatTest3 () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 31 (0x1f)
        .maxstack 4
        .locals init (
            [0] string
        )

        IL_0000: nop
        IL_0001: ldstr "{0}{1}{2}"
        IL_0006: ldc.i4.1
        IL_0007: box [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Int32
        IL_000c: ldc.i4.2
        IL_000d: box [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Int32
        IL_0012: ldc.i4.3
        IL_0013: box [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Int32
        IL_0018: call string [System.Private.CoreLib]System.String::Format(string, object, object, object)
        IL_001d: stloc.0
        IL_001e: ret
    } // end of method Program::FormatTest3

    .method private hidebysig static 
        void FormatTest4 () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x207c
        // Code size 55 (0x37)
        .maxstack 5
        .locals init (
            [0] string
        )

        IL_0000: nop
        IL_0001: ldstr "{0}{1}{2}{3}"
        IL_0006: ldc.i4.4
        IL_0007: newarr [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Object
        IL_000c: dup
        IL_000d: ldc.i4.0
        IL_000e: ldc.i4.1
        IL_000f: box [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Int32
        IL_0014: stelem.ref
        IL_0015: dup
        IL_0016: ldc.i4.1
        IL_0017: ldc.i4.2
        IL_0018: box [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Int32
        IL_001d: stelem.ref
        IL_001e: dup
        IL_001f: ldc.i4.2
        IL_0020: ldc.i4.3
        IL_0021: box [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Int32
        IL_0026: stelem.ref
        IL_0027: dup
        IL_0028: ldc.i4.3
        IL_0029: ldc.i4.4
        IL_002a: box [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Int32
        IL_002f: stelem.ref
        IL_0030: call string [System.Private.CoreLib]System.String::Format(string, object[])
        IL_0035: stloc.0
        IL_0036: ret
    } // end of method Program::FormatTest4

    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x20bf
        // Code size 8 (0x8)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0006: nop
        IL_0007: ret
    } // end of method Program::.ctor

} // end of class Program
```

My questions is:

1. Why string.Format() with 4 or more parameter use arrays?
2. Why FormatTest4()'s MSIL use dup (I know what dup do)？

Comment: 1. Seems to match the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8) for the overloads.

Comment: String.Format() has 3 dedicated overloads to optimize the common cases of having 1, 2 or 3 format parameters.  The buck stops at 4 or more, now you need to pass object[].  The dup is necessary because STELEM requires it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. That's a performance optimization for the most common cases. By having separate overloads for common numbers of parameters they don't have to create the `params` array argument, thus saving an allocation (although may still need boxing, but that's cheaper than an array). Theoretically the overloads for 0, 1, 2, and 3 parameters don't need to exist, as the method that takes a `params object[]` can handle all of them too. It's just more expensive.
2. `dup` duplicates the current item on the stack. `stelem.ref` takes three items from the stack, the array, the index, and the value for that array index, and stores the value at the index in the array. That means that the array reference is no longer on the stack afterwards. Thus the `dup`. We want to retain that array reference on top of the stack since we need to pass it to the method being called, so we create an array, duplicate it, push the index and first item, use `stelem.ref` to store the item in the array, and still have that array reference, which otherwise would be gone.

   There are alternative ways to do this. If you take the code you've copied from the decompiled C# you end up with different IL where the array reference is taken from a local variable each time:

   ```
   IL_0036: ldc.i4.4
   IL_0037: newarr [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Object
   IL_003c: stloc.1
   IL_003d: ldloc.1
   IL_003e: ldc.i4.0
   IL_003f: ldc.i4.1
   IL_0040: box [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Int32
   IL_0045: stelem.ref
   IL_0046: ldloc.1
   IL_0047: ldc.i4.1
   IL_0048: ldc.i4.2
   IL_0049: box [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Int32
   IL_004e: stelem.ref
   ```

   I would believe that to be less efficient than `dup`, but perhaps the JIT doesn't really care either way. The real decompiled C# code would actually be something like this, though:

   ```
   string text = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", new object[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
   ```

   which results in the same IL as

   ```
   string text = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", 1, 2, 3, 4);
   ```